# Retrieve URL from href="#" attribute in Python using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

When trying to get the actual url from a webpage element using the code below, it returns only "#" and not the URL itself as shown in the following print:
[Webpage element inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xqNO.png)

See that when hovering the mouse over the # symbol, the URL is shown.

```
href = WebDriverWait(self.navegador, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#comandoVisualizarItens"))).get_attribute('href')
```

Is there anyway that i can retrieve the correct information instead of getting only the # char?

Comment: if a URL is even applicable you can get it from the location bar after clicking the link.  (Some sites do not update that... they have pages which cannot be shared via URL and are not bookmark-able... it's sort of easy to tell cause the back button usually won't work...sometimes they will show a "shareURL" though...)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the actual URL or part of it is contained in the javascript code in the `onclick` attribute. You should be able to get the javascript code out of the onclick attribute in the same way you get the href attribute and then extract the path `"/some/path"` or maybe even a full URL.

Comment: Unfortunately the onclick js function does not have the url:
https://i.imgur.com/cn0VU2r.png

Comment: I would suggest to search for the javascript functions that are called on click and try to understand how the page works.